# Looping through model objects to check whether a field is populated

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a django project and am trying to figure out how to loop through all of my "task" model objects and check whether the ManyToMany "user" field is populated by user model objects of a certain type or not.

Is there a simple way to iterate over all of the model objects to do this?

Comment: Could you add some example code? Also, have you looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#filter

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate objects. For example, assume that you have a `Task` model similar to:

```
class Task(models.Model):
     users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
     ...
```

then the following query will return all the `Task` objects which has at least one related user who is a "Student":

```
Task.objects.filter(users__type='Student')
```

The double underscore (`__`) tells Django to traverse the many-to-many relation and fetch the `type` column from the `User` table.

Comment: Where does the "users__is_superuser" come from? If my User table has a "type" field which may equal the string "student" how would I check for that? Adding another piece  in the model somewhere?